# What are the origins of French term 'les salamalecs'

Tags: étymologie, linguistique

This word has been described in a previous entry on the site as '*exaggerated shows of politeness, eg when greeting or welcoming someone at a formal event. The word has a negative connotation, being used to stress how time-consuming, hypocritical or meaningless they can be*.' I noticed that the phrase is somewhat similar to the popular Arabic greeting 'As-salaam 'alaykum.' Is this anything to do with the actual origins of the word? And does this mean that the origins of this word disparaging in nature? Am not a French student, merely interested in language!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *salamalec* is borrowed from the Arabic *as-salām 'alayk* "peace (*salām*) on you", the plural of which *salām 'aleykum* can be heard as *salām alek* to a French ear.

The word was first used in 1559 by [Guillaume Postel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Postel) in *La république des Turcs* to refer to a Turkish-style greeting. A century later it started being used in an ironic way to refer to an oriental greeting, first by [Paul Scarron](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Scarron) in his [*Virgile travesti*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgile_travesti) (1648)  :

> Après avoir, comme très sage,
> Avec grande crainte et respect
> Dit par trois fois salamalec.

and then by [Molière](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moli%C3%A8re) in *Le Médecin volant*.

Nowadays the word is derogatory and used to mean an excessive and hypocritical show of politeness.